# Make my Date column (row label) index in R Data Frame

Tags: r, date, indexing, dataframe

Just starting out in R and got my data into a dataframe: It created index column (row label), but I think I want/need the date column to be the row label column (for ease of use in forecast and plot methods) The functions ie forecast are sometimes picking the row label col and I want dates..

```
> fullmatrix
    Date      Unit Sales Average     Selling Price    Median Selling Price  Average Days on Market
161 2000-05-01       3041                114093                99554              138
160 2000-06-01       3079                114730                99931              138
159 2000-07-01       2455                122074                97737              145
```

So How do I 1)drop the index(row label),and 2) declare the date as the index(row label)?

Comment: This is a little confusing, because your terminology doesn't make much sense. I think when you refer to an "index column" you're actually talking about row names. Row names are not columns. Or maybe you're not using a data frame per se, but some sort of time series object with an explicit index? But then, you never mention anything of that sort, so...

Comment: Sorry to be so vague,, the R terminology is new to me, the row names as 3 digit numbers are what I'm trying to eliminate and use the date column as the row names. That may not in fact be my main issue though..  I ran library(xts)
fullmatrix.xts <- xts(x=fullmatrix[,-1],order.by= as.POSIXct(fullmatrix$date))  and got the same results. I am running a arima forecast and then when I plot the results I do not get "forecasted" time periods in the graph I get the row numbers on the labeled axis when I plot before doing the forecast I do get the dates as the x axis labels after I get "row labels"

Comment: it seems that running fullmatrix.xts <- xts(x=fullmatrix[,-1],order.by= as.POSIXct(fullmatrix$date)) converted the data columns to strings from numbers..so I cannot run arima on the result > auto.arima(fullmatrix.xts$Unit.Sales) Error in na.omit.xts(c(x)) : unsupported type –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear. But I think, you can want to create a time serie object. Using `xts` package for example, you can do the following:

```
dat <- read.table(text=' Date      Unit_Sales_Average     Selling_Price    Median_Selling_Price  Average_Days_on_Market
161 2000-05-01       3041                114093                99554              138
160 2000-06-01       3079                114730                99931              138
159 2000-07-01       2455                122074                97737              145',header=TRUE)
library(xts)
dat.xts <- xts(x=dat[,-1],order.by= as.POSIXct(dat$Date))

          Unit_Sales_Average Selling_Price Median_Selling_Price Average_Days_on_Market
2000-05-01               3041        114093                99554                    138
2000-06-01               3079        114730                99931                    138
2000-07-01               2455        122074                97737                    145
```

Now you have index:

```
index(dat.xts)
[1] "2000-05-01 CEST" "2000-06-01 CEST" "2000-07-01 CEST"
```

This xts object can be used within forecast.

Comment: it seems that running fullmatrix.xts <- xts(x=fullmatrix[,-1],order.by= as.POSIXct(fullmatrix$date)) converted the data columns to strings from numbers..so I cannot run arima on the result > auto.arima(fullmatrix.xts$Unit.Sales)
Error in na.omit.xts(c(x)) : unsupported type

Comment: well, how do I specify the variable I want to forecast? ie Unit.Sales? it is one of many columns. As mentioned,, the conversion to an xts object seems to have converted that data in all the columns to strings from numbers? (at least  that is what it looks like when I print "fullmatrix.xts"